# How to load all the answer in Quora

Tags: quora

As I scroll down, more and more answers are getting loaded. Is there any way to load all the answers in one go using JavaScript or a query?

Comment: This is essentially a cross-post of one of your Stack Overflow questions. If you must cross-post (because, for example, you are not getting answers after a couple of days) then do by all means post again. But, always acknowledge your cross-posting - it is rather a breach of netiquette not to. [Please read this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266053/472495).

Comment: @halfer - please share the link - it is a cross post of which question in SO? I am unable to find it.

Comment: @Roland: it looks like it has been deleted (the question is around seven months old). It would have been in their Stack Overflow profile (reachable from their username here) but they no longer have any questions there. It could have been deleted by themselves or a moderator.